# Sending a keystroke to a 16bit DOS application wrapped in NTVDM

Tags: c#, windows, macros, ntvdm, ntvdm.exe

I am trying to send keystrokes to a 16bit DOS application that is wrapped in NTVDM. My code below currently is able to successfully send keystrokes to any application (e.g. Notepad) including the command prompt which makes me wonder why it doesnt work with the DOS application im trying to send to. Though i believe it has something to do with the DOS application being wrapped in NTVDM. Hopefully somebody can give me some clues. At the moment my code below is sending ALT+SPACE to the command prompt and selecting all:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
const int VK_UP = 0x26; //up key
const int VK_DOWN = 0x28;  //down key
const int VK_LEFT = 0x25;
const int VK_RIGHT = 0x27;
const int VK_NUMPAD0 = 0x60;
const int VK_NUMPAD1 = 0x61;
const int VK_NUMPAD2 = 0x62;
const int VK_NUMPAD3 = 0x63;
const int VK_NUMPAD4 = 0x64;
const int VK_NUMPAD5 = 0x65;
const int VK_NUMPAD6 = 0x66;
const int VK_NUMPAD7 = 0x67;
const int VK_NUMPAD8 = 0x68;
const int VK_NUMPAD9 = 0x69;
const int VK_LMENU = 0x12;
const int VK_SPACE = 0x20;

private void btnCMD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application_Methods.GoToCMD();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    byte LMENU = 0x12;
    byte SPACE = 0x20;
    uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey((uint)LMENU, 0);
    uint scanCode1 = MapVirtualKey((uint)SPACE, 0);
    keybd_event(LMENU, (byte)scanCode, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(SPACE, (byte)scanCode1, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(SPACE, (byte)scanCode1, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    keybd_event(LMENU, (byte)scanCode, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    SendKeys.Send("e");
    SendKeys.Send("s");
 }

    public static void GoToCMD()
    {
        //Find the window, using the CORRECT Window Title
        int hWnd = FindWindow("ConsoleWindowClass", "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");
        ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //Activate it

    }
```

Comment: Note that you're not trying to send the keystrokes to the application, you're trying to send them to the console window.  The problem is likely to be in the `GoToCMD()` function, which you haven't shown.

Comment: I added the GoToCMD() code that i left out. All it is doing is finding the window of the application in this case the command prompt and bringing it to the foreground which it does with no problems. Also those particular command im sending (ALT+SPACE) need to be sent to the console window so that i can select all and copy the data output.

Comment: Have you double-checked that the console window actually has the title you're searching for?  (It's been a while, but I have a distant recollection that the title changes when a 16-bit application is launched.)

Comment: Also, try running just the selection code and then hitting ALT-SPACE physically to see whether that works.  And consider using [`ReadConsoleOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead if possible.

Comment: Yep it has the correct title because the DOS application comes to the foreground so i know that works. ALT+SPACE works when i phyically do it. ALT+SPACE is just 1 function that I need to perform within this application, i also need to use number 1-9 and the ESC keys. Its not shown in my code but i have previously tried them all but they dont work in that DOS application, mind you they work in every other application e.g. notepad, microsoft word as well as the command prompt

Comment: For sending input to the DOS application, I suggest you try `WriteConsoleInput` instead.  It might work better.